# The selected stored procedure or function returns no columns when using Oracle SP

Tags: oracle, entity-framework

Visual Studio 2013, Entity Framework 5:
Doing "add function import" for an Oracle stored procedure that has output type of SYS_REFCURSOR. In the "Returns a collection of" - choosing Complex and then clicking on the "Get Column Information" - I keep getting:

> **"The selected stored procedure or function returns no columns".**

I'm aware that the config file (app.config in that case) should include entry for the stored procedure. I generated it:

```
<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
      <implicitRefCursor>
        <storedProcedure schema="<Scheme name>" name="<SP Name>">
          <refCursor name="<ref cursor name>">
           <bindInfo mode="Output" />
          </refCursor>
        </storedProcedure>
      </implicitRefCursor>
    </version>
  </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
```

What am I missing here ? (read lots of posts - none of them helped).
What should be the value of the DBName in the settings entry ? the name of the DB itself ? The name of the connection string entry in the config file ? the name of the entity Framework that was created ?

Answer (score 1):

I found out what the problem was:
1. In the Server Explorer, run the procedure.
2. There's a screen which let you sign the option to include the needed configuration in the config file (see below). In order for the entity framework to generate the model - it should know the fields. In order to achieve this, **need to check the "select for config" option**, and then click "add config" 
This is the relevant screen:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFoTv.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Visual Studio. But, as of DBName you asked about: in Oracle, a connection string looks like connect `username/password@database` where `database` represents its *alias* in the TNSNAMES.ORA file. If you don't have it, you can still connect. Have a look at this example, maybe you'll see something familiar and will be able to use it.

I've removed *confidential* data because Big Brother is watching :), as well as some irrelevant stuff.

I should know database name (db11g) so that I could *ping* it and find out host, port and SID:

```
M:\>tnsping db11g

Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION= (ADDRESS= (PROTOCOL=TCP) (HOST=db_11g) (PORT=1521)) (CONNECT_DATA= (SID=db11g)))
OK (50 msec)
```

OK, now ping the host to find its IP address:

```
M:\>ping db_11g

Pinging db_11g [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=59
```

Finally, connect:

```
M:\>sqlplus scott/tiger@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1521/db11g
                        --------------- 
                        IP address      ----
                                        Port -----
                                             SID

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production

SQL>
```

Hopefully, you'll make it work. If not, sorry, I can't help you any better.